# R | Function "t.test()" vs qnorm : issue with the 95 percent confidence interval

Tags: r

In R, I loaded the `mtcars` data and tried to find the 95 percent confidence of the variable `mpg` interval with `qnorm` :

```
data(mtcars)
with(mtcars, qnorm(p = 0.975,mean = mean(mpg),sd = sd(mpg)))
```

which returns :

```
31.90323
```

And :

```
with(mtcars, qnorm(p = 0.025,mean = mean(mpg),sd = sd(mpg)))
```

returns :

```
8.525658
```

But with the `t.test()` function, the result is different :

```
with(mtcars, t.test(mpg,conf.level = 0.95))
```

I get :

```
95 percent confidence interval:
17.91768 22.26357
```

I don't understand why is that. Please light my lantern.

Comment: well first, you should be using the t distribution, and second the source code is available `stats:::t.test.default`, you can look through there or try `debugonce(stats:::t.test.default)` and run your t test

Answer (score 0):

The confidence interval withe the function `t.test()` is given here for the mean and not for the variable.
To prove this, we can take the result of statistics presenting the standard deviation for the mean as :

[Standard deviation of mean : click here](https://i.sack.imgur.com/8R3Fw.png)

Proof :

```
with(mtcars, qnorm(p = 0.975,mean = mean(mpg),sd = sd(mpg)/sqrt(length(mpg))))
with(mtcars, qnorm(p = 0.025,mean = mean(mpg),sd = sd(mpg)/sqrt(length(mpg))))
```

Returns :

```
22.17882
18.00243
```

It's not far from the values given by `t.test()` but still not equal. Why is that ?

Comment: t.test() uses the Student's t-distribution, not the normal distribution.  For 31 degrees of freedom, the 0.975 value of that distribution is 2.039513, not 1.959964.. Thus `mean(mpg) +/- 2.039513*se` results in slightly wider interval limits

Comment: Yes, I understand perfectly now. Thanks @langtang